# Por qué no funciona la API landsatxplore.api?

Tags: python

No funciona landsatxplore.api?

Estaba descargando el dataset de Landsat 8 y 9 con la API landsatxplore.api. Pero hace un par de dias me ha dado un error (landsatxplore.errors.USGSError: UNAUTHORIZED_USER: Unable to validate user API permissions.)

Como puedo resolver el problema para que descargue el dataset correctamente???

script

```py
import landsatxplore.api  

api = landsatxplore.api.API('USER', 'PASSWORD')

scenesLandsat = api.search( dataset='landsat_ot_c2_l1', latitude=Lat, longitude=Long, start_date=FechaPasado , end_date=FechaActual, max_cloud_cover=cloud, max_results=2)

api.logout()
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ahi dice que no tenes permisos...

Comment: Seguro que ese usuario y contraseña son correctos? Válidos? Revisa en la documentación si no los has generado y cómo puedes usarlos correctamente https://pypi.org/project/landsatxplore/

Comment: El USER y PASSWORD son otros pero estan puestos de la misma forma...